# downloading instagram page to the iframe

Tags: html

I try to download instagram page to the iframe.
Code below:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Title</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <iframe src="https://www.instagram.com"></iframe>
 <button> Start </button>
 </body>
 </html>
```

But it doesn’t work because of instagram header option x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN?
How can I make it work?
please, help

Comment: whats the error ?

Answer (score 1):

You should have the `<iframe>` as follow:

```
<iframe src="http://instagram.com/p/a1wDZKopa2/embed" width="500" height="580" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Especially including `/embed` after your `src` url